# Camunda 7: Database query to extract FNI usage by process

Tags: camunda

Good day -

I’m familar with the query to extract the total FNI count from a Camunda 7 database for a period, but I’d like to get more granularity - breakdown by BPMN definition ideally. However, I’m struggling to put that together from the database. The numbers per node are displayed in the Enterprise Cockpit so they must be available - could someone assit with extracting them?

This would assist me in identifying the most complex and expensive processes.Good day -

I’m familar with the query to extract the total FNI count from a Camunda 7 database for a period, but I’d like to get more granularity - breakdown by BPMN definition ideally. However, I’m struggling to put that together from the database. The numbers per node are displayed in the Enterprise Cockpit so they must be available - could someone assit with extracting them?

This would assist me in identifying the most complex and expensive processes.

This is the query from the Camunda documentation showing FNI usage per Camunda database/instance, but I can't see a way to extend this to get more granular information:

```
SELECT 'FNI' AS Metric, 
ISNULL(SUM(VALUE_), 0) AS [Count] 
FROM ACT_RU_METER_LOG 
WHERE NAME_ = 'activity-instance-start' AND TIMESTAMP_ BETWEEN '01 Jan 2022' AND '31 Dec 2022'
```

Answer (score 0):

After some digging in the database I have developed the following query which shows FNI per process definition.  The sum of the FNI values from this query aren't a perfect match for the official FNI count query above, but the difference is small enough (1%) for my purposes.

*Note that on a large/busy database these tables can get very large and running this query could impact Camunda's performance.*

```
SELECT act.PROC_DEF_KEY_ AS ProcessDefinition,
       COUNT(*) FNI
FROM ACT_HI_ACTINST act WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN ACT_HI_PROCINST procinst  WITH (NOLOCK) ON procinst.PROC_INST_ID_ = act.PROC_INST_ID_
WHERE act.START_TIME_ BETWEEN '01 Mar 2023' AND '31 Mar 2023'
AND procinst.STATE_ NOT IN ('ACTIVE')
GROUP BY act.PROC_DEF_KEY_
ORDER BY act.PROC_DEF_KEY_
```